# Prevent page reloading in Struts 2

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am currently working on a small web app and this is the first time i am using Struts2. Here is what i am trying to achieve.

A Struts2 JSP page on form post, calls a struts action. Once this action completes it task, I need to return to the calling JSP with out any page reloading (avoid postback).
how can i  achieve.can any one please help me?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called **[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)** (no kidding).

In Struts2 you can use **[Struts2-jQuery Plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)** to achieve that pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

As AndreaLigios said, you can achieve this using struts-j query plug-in.

1. Create a remote page to display your result.
2. use 
   `<sj:sbmit targets="[div_id]" />`
   on your main page to submit the form
3. Add a div to your main page to display the remote page. 
   `<div id="[div_id]" />`
4. In your struts.xml, just return the remote page as a result of your action.